# HttpContext.Current.Session is throwing exception(Object reference not set to an instance of an object.) in business class

Tags: asp.net, session

In our application we have to access session objects in business class. We are using HttpContext.Current.Session to get the session value. In some cases it returns the value but mostly its throwing a null reference exception(Object reference not set to an instance of an object). We have the following code
Try

If HttpContext.Current.Session("Username") IsNot Nothing then 
     ' Statements to be executed
  End If
Catch ex As Exception
  'Log to db
End Try

Here HttpContext.Current.Session("Username") is mostly throwing an exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
While debugging we found that HttpContext.Current itself is nothing.

Thanks. Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Is the code definitely executing within the context of a request to your web application and not in an application start up event in which case there would be no HttpContext

Comment: The fact that "some cases it returns the value but mostly not.." points to @Nick Champion being on the right track. It's bad practice to access the httpcontext outside the web app, as it stops the class library from being used outside a web app.

Comment: hi i am able to get the value of HttpContext.Current.Session("Username") apart from this all the values getting exception as Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score -2):

If the production machine is IIS, there is an installation of "WebSocket protocol".

If the production machine is nginx, you need to set "proxy_set_header Connection" Upgrade ";".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: sample
server {
     server_name yyy.domain * .yyy.domain;
     location / {
         proxy_pass http: // localhost: 5000;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $ http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade"; ← Changed like this
         proxy_set_header Host $ host;
         proxy_cache_bypass $ http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $ proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $ scheme;
     }
}

Comment: I wrote it in English.

Comment: Your recent comment contains a lot of unformatted code. If that is intended to be part of the answer then please [edit] it into the answer, nicely formatted, and delete the comment.

Comment: Separately, please code-format (with backticks) any code within the answer.